# How to decode a signed PGP message using Python after decrypting it by a private key?

Tags: cryptography, pgp

I am trying to read a signed PGP message. After I decrypt it by my private key successfully, I get another PGP message that can decrypt again using gpg --decrypt to get the plaintext form (I have the public key of signer, however, gpg --decrypt can get plaintext form without public key, reasons are explained here: [In gpg, "decrypting" a signed message without the public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201070/in-gpg-decrypting-a-signed-message-without-the-public-key?rq=3). Is there a way to use python to decrypt without naming any key, similar to the way gpg --decrypt can do?

gpg requires installing GnuPG, that I want to avoid because my script needs to be run on Airflow server later.

I tried with pgpy module, but no hope. pgpy always asks for a key to perform decrypting actions. I understand it is just the work of decoding now, but cannot find other python modules to do it.